# Create servlet and JSP in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using `intellij idea 12 community edition`, I think I need to install Java EE plugin for creating `servlet` and `JSP`, But I can't find this plugin nowhere!

I looked up in `settings`, `project structure` and `install jetBrains plugins`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to create just servlet and jsp pages, you can simply add `servlet-api` and `jsp-api` jar files to your IDE.

Answer (score 4):

That's only an [IntelliJ Ultimate Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) feature.  If you want it, you'll have to pay for a license.